# How to cleanup useEffect in React Native while using React Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using random user api to fetch user information with setInterval function and my useEffect looks like this;

```
// Users.js

useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = () => {
      fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) =>
          setUsers((prevUsers) => {
            return setUsers([
              ...prevUsers,
              { key: data.results[0].login.uuid, value: data.results[0] },
            ]);
          })
        );

      console.log("cleanup?");
    };
    getUser();
    // const userInterval = setInterval(getUser, 5000);
    // return () => clearInterval(userInterval);
  }, []);
```

I use react navigation to display each user's details in another page and navigate like this;

```
 <TouchableOpacity
 onPress={() => navigation.navigate("userDetails", item.value)}>
```

So when I nagivate to details page, useEffect doesn't return which means component doesn't unmount. It actually makes because of the stack navigation, pages are basically on top of each and still running. So how can I stop my interval function in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These scenarios are covered in the docs of react-navigation.

From [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle):

> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
> them. We can listen to focus and blur events to know when a screen
> comes into focus or goes out of focus respectively.

Example:

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // Screen was focused
      // Do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

Or with the help of `useFocusEffect` hook above code can be simplified to this.

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile() {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused

      return () => {
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

Comment: this is cool, but why do we need useCallback hook?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/), `Note: To avoid the running the effect too often, it's important to wrap the callback in useCallback before passing it to useFocusEffect as shown in the example.`